# Manipulate connections between elements dropped on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

Here I have been able to drop elements onto a canvas and create connections between them. But every time I drag a dropped element within the canvas, the anchors do not move along with the dragged element. Instead when I try to create a connection from the isolated anchor to another element it immediately re-positions itself with its parent element. This is one issue and I would also like to delete the anchors/ connections whenever its parent element is deleted.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.jsPlumb-1.6.4-min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .chevron-toolbox{
            position: absolute;
            width: 72px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color: powderblue;
            background-image: url("../dist/img/bigdot.png");
            border: solid 3px red;
        }

        #dropArea{
            cursor: pointer;
            border: solid 1px gray;
            width: 800px;
            margin-left: 80px;
            height: 400px;
            position: relative;
            overflow-x: scroll;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }

        .chevron {

            position:absolute;
            cursor:pointer;
            width: 72px;
            height: 80px;
            background-color:  powderblue;
            background-image: url("../dist/img/bigdot.png");

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chevron-toolbox" id="cId">
    </div>
    <div id="dropArea">
    </div>

    <button id="go">Double Click Me</button>
    <script>
        jsPlumb.ready(function(e)
        {
            jsPlumb.setContainer($('#dropArea'));
            $(".chevron-toolbox").draggable
            ({
                helper : 'clone',
                cursor : 'pointer',
                tolerance : 'fit',
                revert : true

            });

            $("#dropArea").droppable
            ({
                accept : '.chevron-toolbox',
                containment : 'dropArea',

                drop : function (e, ui) {
                    droppedElement = ui.helper.clone();
                    ui.helper.remove();
                    $(droppedElement).removeAttr("class");
                    jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
                    $(droppedElement).addClass("chevron");
                    $(droppedElement).draggable({containment: "dropArea"});
                    $(droppedElement).appendTo('#dropArea');
                    setId(droppedElement);
                    var droppedId = $(droppedElement).attr('id');
                    var common = {
                        isSource:true,
                        isTarget:true,
                        connector: ["Flowchart"],
                    };

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(droppedId, {
                        anchors:["Right"]
                    }, common);

                    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(droppedId, {
                        anchors:["Left"]
                    }, common);
                    alert(droppedId);

                    //Delete an element on double click
                    var dataToPass = {msg: "Confirm deletion of Item"};
                    $(droppedElement).dblclick(dataToPass, function(event) {
                        alert(event.data.msg);
                        $(this).remove();
                    });



                }

            });

            //Set a unique ID for each dropped Element
            var indexer = 0;
            function setId(element){
                indexer++;
                element.attr("id",indexer);

            }

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share the relevant code snippets also.

Comment: I've provided the modified code above. I was able to assign unique IDs to the dropped elements and create connections. Now the issue that I am dealing with is mentioned above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly manipulate the connections, you can use the [`connect` method in jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/connect-examples.html) placing anchors at desired points.

```
jsPlumb.connect({
  source:'window2',
  target:'window3',
  paintStyle:{lineWidth:8, strokeStyle:'rgb(189,11,11    )'},
  anchors:["Bottom", "Top"],
  endpoint:"Rectangle"
});
```

This is merely an example. Following this pattern in your implementation will be useful when it comes to accessing details regarding those connections and deleting the connections alongside the elements